# SQL Server: Is there a way to test if INSERT would succeed without actually inserting

Tags: debugging, insert, sql-server-2000

So, I am debugging a pretty complex financial reporting application, where almost all of the business logic is handled through stored procedures.

I am debugging a particular call stack of various stored procedures and I was wondering if there was any way in SQL Server 2000 to actually test if an insert would be successful without actually doing an insert.

I hope my question makes sense.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the insert in a transaction, check for success, and then rollback.

Comment: Actually, in my situation, some of the tables I deal with has millions of rows.. doing a commit and rollback would lock up the database for a couple of hours..

Answer (score 2):

Not really. You could wrap things in a transaction, and then roll it back after seeing if it worked or not.